# Insert into SQL table using Loop

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have two tables

- `Chapters_tbl` (chID, name)
- `Status_tbl` (chID, Ch_status)

For every `chID` in `Chapters_tbl`, I want to insert that `chID` into `Status_tbl` and `Ch_status`

I can use both a SQL Server stored procedure or Entity Framework in C#.

How can I do this?

Comment: Microsoft's documentation shows how to use both EF and SQL in order to perform inserts; [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx) specifically talks about how to use map EF calls into stored procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using T-SQL...

```
INSERT dbo.Status_tbl (chID, Ch_status)
SELECT 
    c.chID,
    Ch_status = 1
FROM 
    dbo.Chapters c
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM dbo.Staus_tbl s 
                WHERE c.chID = s.chID
                );
```

Comment: what is c here and Ch_status value is not coming from an other table it is 1

Comment: "c" is the table alias for the Chapters table. As far as the Ch_status comment... You OP states, "I want to insert that chID in Status_tbl and Ch_status"... Which I read as "I want chID inserted into both columns... I've updated my answer to insert a 1 into that column.